# Generate 1 min time interval from current time in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime

I have a scenario where I want to generate 1 min time difference from current time past in epoch(seconds) and save them in two int type variables for example t1 (current time) & t2 (time one min ago). How do I acheive that ?

I have explored date time module but not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from datetime import datetime

t1 = int(datetime.now().timestamp())
t2 = t1 - 60
```

Comment: This gives decimal as well , How do I eliminate the decimal part ?
`1584806243.021152` I would need only 1584806243

Comment: Just use `int(t1)`. Note: the 2 calls to `datetime.now()` will potentially have different values so `-60` might only `59` seconds. You could just do `t2 = t1-60` to ensure they are `60` seconds apart.

Comment: @rahlf23 `t2-t1-60` gives error , can you provide the example

Comment: I've edited my answer accordingly. And why would you do `t2-t1-60`? What would that achieve?

Answer (score 1):

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

now = datetime.now()
print(now)
one_minute_ago = now - timedelta(seconds=60)
print(one_minute_ago)

# or directly
print(datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=60))
```

output

```
2020-03-21 17:59:14.315156
2020-03-21 17:58:14.315156
2020-03-21 17:58:14.3152
```

EDIT: in epoch format

```
print(int(one_minute_ago.timestamp()))
# or
print(int((datetime.now() - timedelta(seconds=60)).timestamp()))
```

Comment: I would need it in epoch format and without the decimal part `1584806243`